# Haskell fmt library not found

Tags: haskell

When I import the Haskell Fmt module, I get the information
"Could not find module 'Fmt'.
It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package".

```
GHCi, version 9.2.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> :set -XOverloadedStrings
ghci> import Fmt

<no location info>: error:
Could not find module `Fmt'
It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
ghci>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays one uses `cabal repl` rather than `ghci`:

```
cabal repl --build-depends fmt
...
Prelude> :set -XOverloadedStrings 
Prelude> import Fmt
Prelude Fmt> let (a, b, n) = ("foo", "bar", 25)
Prelude Fmt> ("Here are some words: "+|a|+", "+|b|+"\nAlso a number: "+|n|+"") :: String
"Here are some words: foo, bar\nAlso a number: 25"
```